# Ipython notebook nbconvert slides as a page in another reveal.js presentation

Tags: plotly, reveal.js, jupyter-notebook

I have a `plot.ly` interactive plot that I would like to add to my `reveal.js` presentation. When I use 
`ipython nbconvert --to slides asd.ipynb` I get a working reveal presentation consisting of a single slide. My question is how can I augment this `nbconvert` generated slide into my original presentation consisting of many slides.

When I investigate the nbconvert generated html via Sublime, it turns out that the html is more than 400 lines. I can copy the content into my original presentation as the n-th slide, however that seems too impractical to me.

To rephrase my question: how can I embed a ipython notebook plot as the n-th slide in my reveal presentation?